# Awareness.SnapshotApi.getPlaces return placeResult with null Likelihoods

Tags: google-awareness

Awareness.SnapshotApi.getPlaces return placeResult with status Successful and null likelihoods. Google Maps shows that i'm in specific place.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had the same result earlier but didn't bother digging deeper right now. I just assumed it was because there are no Places close to me right now. (I am in a remote area)

Comment: I tried to change my location with fake gps but result was the same.